# animating using angular animate

Tags: css, angularjs

I use .ng-hide to set height to 0px

```
.ng-hide .bar {
  height: 0px;
}
```

and then when .ng-hide is remove the height is set to 5px;

```
.bar {
  transition: height linear 2.5s;
  border-width: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  height: 5px;
}
```

However I don't see any transition happening. 
(I expected the results to be like: http://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_animation_css )

Not sure what I am missing here:

Plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/B5LBwKSmL13BOoGuBhSx?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting from version `1.2` of AngularJS, animations are not a part of the core anymore.

So this means that you have to include the `angular-animate.js` file into your webpage and reference the `ngAnimate` module inside of your application module

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-animate.js"></script>


var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ngAnimate']);
```

Comment: for some reason i thought including ngAnimate was optional

Comment: @runtimeZero did a little research and it looks that  from version 1.1.5 to 1.2 `ng-animate` got seperated from the AngularJS core so you have to include it on your own